# Приложение Android кол-во Активити

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте,  хотел бы поинтересоваться, из скольки активити должно состоять полноценное приложение(или же одно активити и фрагменты)?  Как сильно их количество влияет на размер апк?

Comment: Встречный вопрос: что такое полноценное приложение?

Comment: Которое не является отработкой того или иного метода. Грубо говоря,  которым уже могут пользоваться люди

Comment: А что за приложение, которым люди не могут пользоваться?

Comment: Например,  учебное: текстовое поле, кнопка и вывод результата.

Comment: Но им же люди могут пользоваться? Могут. Собственно непонятно к чему  вообще вам эти знания.

Comment: Меня волнует как было бы правильнее. Использовать фрагменты или активити. И насколько сильно кол-во активити повышает размер апк

Comment: А что вам размер АПК? Решили на спичках экономить?

Comment: Я некогда делал весьма полезное приложение, которое состоит из одного активити, которое выполняет свою работу и мгновенно закрывается, даже анимация открытия сработать не успевает. Ни одного фрагмента, лишь одно активити, и этим уже можно пользоваться. У вас сломана метрика "полезности".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вопрос похож на "Собрался строить дом - сколько обычно комнат в доме".

У каждого свое понятие о полноценном приложении. И количество активити в приложении зависит не от хорошего тона, а от необходимостей разработчика.

У вас может не быть  вообще активити: если вы делаете службу, которая выводит все данные в строку уведомлений.

У вас может быть одна активити - если приложение просто выводит какую-то информацию и требует нажатия пары кнопок от пользователя.

Может быть огромное число активити - если речь идет о сложном приложении, которое различными способами взаимодействует с пользователем, использует множество форм и способов отображения информации.

Т.е. данный вопрос не имеет смысла - каждому свое.